# How to trap UIThreadException and UnhandledException in Windows Forms, Net Framework

Tags: winforms, exception, .net-4.8, unhandled-exception

There is MS documentation about trap exception https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

But this documentation is theoretical and don't bound to Windows Forms and Visual Studio 2022, In Visual studio we have special button to handle exception

[image: Handle exception on Visual studio]

This class allow to trap only one exception UnhandledException. I need to trap second exception, because I have sophisticated multiThreading application.

I created this simple test to trap ThreadException

```
Public Shared Sub ThreadExceptionEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
        MsgBox(e.Exception, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ThreadExceptionEventHandler")
End Sub

Private Async Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf ThreadExceptionEventHandler '

    Await Task.Run(Sub()
                       Throw New Exception("test exception")
                   End Sub)
    ....
```

and in class MyApplication try to trap Unhadled exception

```
Partial Friend Class MyApplication
    Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(sender As Object, e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
            MsgBox(e.Exception, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "UnhandledException")
    End Sub
...
```

So, it's look as any exception must catch by my code, isn't it? But no. Starting code with Visual studio show unhandled error

[image: Unhandled error]

Starting program on console don't show anything, program shutdown without any error message, this means trap any exception don't working. Why?

Also. pay attention that ThreadException not available in class MyApplication.

[image: ThreadException not available in class MyApplication]

Comment: I think I've already *suggested* moving that code away from the `Load` event handler and to **not** subscribe to `ThreadException`  there. Do that in the body of the `MyApplication` class. If you want - though not needed here - you can also override its `OnUnhandledException()` -- The execution halts by default when the debugger is attached, not when the executable is run, of course. Press F5 to continue. Also see [Exceptions in managed threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/exceptions-in-managed-threads)

Comment: @Jimi, maybe you are right, but I still don't understand you. Thread exception NOT available in class MyApplication, there are special comments from MS in that class, se please last screen. And, of course, press F5 doing nothing, instead working my code application just finished, exception on screen is final state, not state before ThreadException handler working. So, question is opened, where and why exactly is possible to trap ThreadException? And Why UnhandledException not fired in this simple test?

Comment: In MyApplication, override `OnStartup()` and add `AddHandler System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException, AddressOf ThreadExceptionEventHandler`. Add the `ThreadExceptionEventHandler` method in this class. Start the application without debugger attached (CTRL+F5) -- If you want to use the AppDomain's `UnhandledException` (the last fence before shutdown), override or subscribe to that event, comment out the subscription to `Application.ThreadException` and start without debugging (if you handle `ThreadException`, then `UnhandledException` is not raised because the exception is *handled*)

Comment: @thank you, jimi, finally you point me correct solution, I will publish full solution below

Comment: Note that some parts apply to .NET Framework, not .NET, where you can start with the debugger attached. When the exception is raised, in Visual Studio the code execution halts anyway (you could change that, it doesn't really matter here), but you can press F5 and the code will resume in the `ThreadException` or `UnhandledException` handlers

Comment: yes, of course I try to start testing error handler on console, without VS2022

Answer (score 0):

According @Jimi advice, final solution is there

```
Partial Friend Class MyApplication

    Public Shared Sub ThreadExceptionEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
        Dim Data() As Byte = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Exception.Message)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(IO.Path.Combine(IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), Now.ToBinary.ToString & ".txt"), Data, True)
    End Sub

    Private Overloads Sub OnStartup()
        AddHandler System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException, AddressOf ThreadExceptionEventHandler
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
        My.Application.DoEvents()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(sender As Object, e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
        Dim Data() As Byte = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Exception.Message)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(IO.Path.Combine(IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), Now.ToBinary.ToString & ".txt"), Data, True)
    End Sub
```

Add 2 small comments to Jimi advice:
(1) Msgbox (and maybe all windows forms) don't working in this workflow, I have simple write exception on file, in this case it's working.
(2) alternative way I use very often in multiThreading application (but unfortunately alternative way is impossible in my current program) - is starting Windows forms app as console application, and than console application open windows forms further, after binding to all windows forms event will done. In this case black console screen appears on short time and only than Windows forms appears.

but with overloading or overriding onStartup on MyApplication is workable and more simple way, thanks Jimi. And, of course, if we want to trap ONLY thread exception, trap common Unhandled exception need to comment.

according @Jimi comment, overriding is also workable solution

```
    Protected Overrides Function OnStartup(e As StartupEventArgs) As Boolean
        AddHandler System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException, AddressOf ThreadExceptionEventHandler
        Return MyBase.OnStartup(e)
    End Function
```

Comment: You can of course override the `OnStartup()` method (that's the default behavior), it's just `Protected Overrides Function OnStartup(e As StartupEventArgs) As Boolean ' Your code here Return MyBase.OnStartup(e) End Function` -- When you override the method ,you don't also handle the event (`OnStartup()` is the method that raises the event)

Comment: @Jimi, yes, you are right, overriding in possible too